Seaborn lineplot errorbar=None gives AttributeError
I am getting this error with errorbar=None attribute
I am getting attribute error. My code works without errorbar attribute. The syntax is consistent with the seaborn documentation.
It works without errorbar attribute:
#ax = sns.lineplot(x='YEAR', y='SUNACTIVITY', data=sunspots_data,  errorbar=None, ax=ax)
ax = sns.lineplot(x='YEAR', y='SUNACTIVITY', data=sunspots_data,  ax=ax)

Documentation:

errorbar string, (string, number) tuple, or callable
Name of errorbar method (either “ci”, “pi”, “se”, or “sd”), or a tuple with a method name and a level parameter, or a function that maps from a vector to a (min, max) interval, or None to hide errorbar. See the errorbar tutorial for more information.


Which seaborn version are you using (print(sns.__version__))? The online documentation refers to seaborn 0.13.2.  Note that at StackOverflow you are supposed to add error messages as text inside the main post, not as image

Please provide a minimal reproducible code so others can better understand and reproduce your problem.

It was Seaborne version issue. I was able to reinstall newer version and the issue got resolved
